# how can I stop resharper from complaining about html5 boilerplate html tags?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, resharper-7.1

standard html5 boilerplate layout

`<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->`

then complains that the `</html>` tag is an *unmatched closing tag*

I thought it was visual studio, I pasted into a new layout and noticed it wasn't complaining.
When I turned on Resharper the error reappeared.

How can I turn stop this distracting false-positive error?

Comment: Looks like a bug; reported here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-362978 -- please feel free to vote and add comments.

Comment: Duplicate issue - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-287707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a resharper upgrade to >= 8.0.6.335 may be the only way according to the issue.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-287707